# browsersync.reload task is not finishing

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I have a few tasks running to manage my javascript, these are the tasks:

```
gulp.task('watch:js', function() {
    return gulp.watch(local.js,
        gulp.series('babel', 'cleanJsBundles', 'browserify', 'reload'));
});

gulp.task('reload', function() {
    return browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('watch', gulp.parallel('watch:sass', 'watch:svgsingles', 'watch:js'));
```

Everything works in order - after browserify, the browser reloads. But then everything freezes. In the shell I can see that 'reload' starts, but is not finishing. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

It seems there's a problem with this custom task reload, could you try this:

```
gulp.task('watch:js', function() {
    return gulp.watch(local.js, gulp.series('babel', 'cleanJsBundles', 'browserify')).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['watch:sass', 'watch:svgsingles', 'watch:js']);
```

Comment: ~so now, it is running and finishing, but its not actually reloading the browser.~  nvm - there was just a hiccup, its working, thank you!